# Add and Remove selected items of a checkbox from java ArrayList

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a function that dynamicaly builds checkboxes according to the values of an ArrayList,

Now I want to add those items to another ArrayList when checked and Remove them when Uncheck.

Adding when Item is checked is working but when I uncheck the checkbox it goes back to previous activity.

public void BuildCheckBox(){

```
    FinalSeatList.removeAll(FinalReservedSeatList);

    //Build checkboxus
    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_view);
    for(int i = 0; i < FinalSeatList.size(); i++) {
        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(FinalSeatList.get(i));
        l1.addView(cb);
        final int finalI = i;
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                    SelectedSeatList.add(FinalSeatList.get(finalI));
                    Toast.makeText(SelectSeatsActivity.this, "Added: " + SelectedSeatList.get(finalI), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(SelectedSeatList.contains(FinalSeatList.get(finalI))){
                        SelectedSeatList.remove(FinalSeatList.get(finalI));
                        Toast.makeText(SelectSeatsActivity.this, "Removed: " + SelectedSeatList.get(finalI), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(SelectSeatsActivity.this, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            }

        });
    }




}
```

Comment: can you please mention the error log that you are getting when you performed uncheck operation.

Comment: @Aniket It doesnt give any error on logcat

Comment: in your question description, you mentioned that you get an error ... What error it is?

Comment: @Aniket It just goes back to previous activity, I edited the question. sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

Declaring i as final was the problem, I used getText method for the checkbox insted of going for the array item, and it worked.

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        SelectedSeatList.add((String) cb.getText());
                        Toast.makeText(SelectSeatsActivity.this, "Added: " + (String) cb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        if(SelectedSeatList.contains((String) cb.getText())){
                            SelectedSeatList.remove((String) cb.getText());
                            Toast.makeText(SelectSeatsActivity.this, "Removed: " + (String) cb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(SelectSeatsActivity.this, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this listener in your activity like this -

```
public class ClassName extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
```

then to create dynamic checkbox-

```
LinearLayout checkboxLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chkboxlyt);

  for(int i=0;i<dynamicCheckBoxes.length;i++){
   CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
   cb.setText("whaterever text);
   checkboxLayout.addView(cb);
   cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

You will have this method bcoz you already implement the listener in your activity.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked){
  String checkedText = cb.getText()+"";

  if(isChecked){
   Toast.makeText(this, cb.getText()+" is checked!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
   // do remove operation here
  }
 }
```